# How do I link to non-Docusaurus-defined routes from a Docusuarus footer?

Tags: react-router, docusaurus

Documentation for my website is built with [Docusaurus](https://v2.docusaurus.io/), and I'm currently using the latest release, 2.0.0-alpha.61.

Compiled documentation is saved to the `/docs` directory of my website, while most of the rest of my site is built with GatsbyJS.  So... if you hit `/docs/something` you arrive at a Docusaurus-built page, but if you hit `/contact` or `/about-us` or whatever, you hit a page built using GatsbyJS.

My `docusaurus.config.js` contains:

```
  baseUrl: "/docs/",
...
  presets: [
    [
      "@docusaurus/preset-classic",
      {
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: require.resolve("./sidebars/index.js"),
          showLastUpdateTime: true,
          routeBasePath: "",
        },
...
```

so that Docusaurus is aware that it lives in /docs.

Here's my issue: In the footer of pages created in Docusaurus I'd like to link to /contact or /about-us, etc., on the main page.

The footer portion of `docusaurus.config.js` allows you to have links like this:

```
{
    label: "Github",
    href: "https://github.com/my-org/my-repo",
},
```

or this:

```
{
    label: "Contributing",
    to: "/docs/contributing",
}
```

However, if you do something like this:

```
{
    label: "About Us",
    href: "/about-us",
},
```

You get an error noting that `/about-us` is not a valid url.  The error states `ValidationError: "footer.links[0].items[0].href" must be a valid uri`.  Presumably this is because `/about-us` isn't prepended with `https://`.  I'd like to avoid defining absolute URLs, since I want to be able to stamp out qa, staging, and prod environments for the website and docs.

If you instead do something like this:

```
{
    label: "About Us",
    to: "/about-us",
},
```

Then it compiles, but Docusaurus' React router intercepts the link when clicked, directs you to https://my-site.com/about-us, but shows a Docusaurus 404 "not found" page since Docusaurus' react router is not aware of an /about-us page.  If you refresh the page you see the appropriate "about us" page from GatsbyJS, since Docusaurus' React router doesn't get in the way if you hit the page directly.

What would be the best way to link to my GatsbyJS-generated pages from the Docusaurus footer?  I "[swizzled](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/using-themes/#swizzling-theme-components)" the footer and have as hack in place right now where my `docusaurus.config.js` links have an additional property:

```
{
    label: "About Us",
    to: "/about-us",
    localLink: true,
},
```

and I have an `if` clause in my swizzled component that creates an `<a>` tag if `localLink` is true, and creates a normal React link component otherwise, but I'm not a huge fan of swizzling out components with an alpha release of Docusaurus.

Is there a better way to link to my main page from the footer?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to [submit a PR](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/3254) to Docusaurus to enable relative links on `href:` blocks, but it was denied because they would like `href`'s to have fully qualified domain names in the URLs.

So, there are a few options you can do if you run into this issue:

---

**Option 1**: Make your `href:` targets full URLs.  This requires foreknowledge of where your docs will eventually live.  If, for example, you have an environment variable `MY_DOMAIN=https://my.company.com`, you can update your `docusaurus.config.js` to read:

```
{
  label: 'About Us',
  href: process.env.MY_DOMAIN + '/about-us',
},
```

Note that if you follow this path, you cannot generate your artifacts once and deploy them to multiple environments (like QA, staging, prod, etc.).  That URL in your environment variable is statically compiled in.

---

**Option 2**: Use React `<Link>` components with the `to:` syntax, but target `_blank`:

```
{
  label: 'About Us',
  to: '/about-us',
  target: '_blank' 
},
```

This option has two drawbacks. If your `baseUrl` in `docusaurus.config.js` is anything but `/`, that `baseUrl` will be prepended to your target URL.  So, if `baseUrl='/docs/'`, then the link will open `/docs/about-us`.  Also, links open up in a new window.  This option only really works for you if `baseUrl='/'` and you're okay with links opening in new windows.

---

**Option 3:** Account for your `baseUrl`, and target `_parent` instead.  This option is similar to option 2 with two notable differences:

```
{
  label: 'About Us',
  to: '../about-us',
  target: '_parent' 
},
```

First, your `to:` target accounts for your `baseUrl` by driving your link a directory up.  So, you'll end up at `/docs/../about-us` (or `/about-us`).  Second, your target of `_parent` causes the React router to not capture your click, so your browser window *actually* changes location.  So, clicking the "About Us" link actually results in winding up on the `/about-us` page.

If you choose option 3, when you compile your Docusaurus site you will run into an issue where your React router will claim it can't resolve `/about-us` (which it can't, but that doesn't matter since another site handles that path).  It will prevent your site from compiling, though.  To override that warning, add

```
  onBrokenLinks: "ignore",
```

to your `docusaurus.config.js`.

---

**Option 4**: You can always [swizzle](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/using-themes/#swizzling-theme-components) a component, like the NavBar or Footer, and edit it to your heart's content, thereby avoiding any `docusaurus.config.js` validation issues.